# Keywords Not Working in Google Search

Tags: tags, keyword

I recently built this site (http://www.sykeshr.co.uk), and am having problems when trying to search for the site using the keywords in Google.

These are the keywords I've set:

```
<meta name="keywords" content="sykes, hr, sykeshr, human, resources, infrastructure, projects, buckinghamshire, slough, gerrards, cross, gerrards cross, london, recruitment, beaconsfield, chalfont st peter, amersham, chesham, performance, consultant, consultancy, personnel" />
```

But for some reason, I can only get Google to return the site if I explicitly search for "sykes hr" or "sykeshr". For example, if I search "sykes hr buckinghamshire", Google doesn't return the site.

Any idea why this is? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

If its recently uploaded it will take some time for search engines to detected/ re-index it. You can how ever ask google or Bing through the webtools for a re-index.